# Getting current value when dragging canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, drag

I am trying to make a simple card game, something like Solitaire.
I am not experienced in coding, so forgive me if it's a simple question.

I want to move some canvas objects. New objects have the right value, but when i am dragging an already existing card it shows the wrong value (waarde in Dutch). I would like to bind the value (waarde) to a card, but don't know how to do that...

Thought about tags, binding, ID....

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

window = Tk()

deck = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

def pakkaart():
    rand_card = randint(0,len(deck)-1)
    global waarde
    waarde = deck[rand_card]
    deck.pop(rand_card)
    global kaart
    kaart = Canvas(window, width = 40, height = 40, bg='yellow')
    kaart.place(x=50, y=50, anchor=CENTER)
    kaart.create_text(20,20,text=(waarde))
    kaart.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag)


def drag(event):
    event.widget.place(x=event.x_root, y=event.y_root,anchor=CENTER)    
    print(waarde)

button1 = Button(window, text="Nieuwe Kaart", command=pakkaart)
button1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

So essentially looking for a way to bind a value to a canvas.

Comment: I can't find anything wrong while dragging the cards. The only thing i see is that you will exhaust your `deck` after 6 clicks and thus raise a `ValueError`.

Answer (score 0):

Your above code works fine, it shows the correct value, but if you want you can try this

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

window = Tk()
ws = window.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = window.winfo_screenheight()
w = 500  # width for the Tk root
h = 300  # height for the Tk root
x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)

window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

deck = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]


def pick_card():
    global waarde, kaart
    rand_card = randint(0, len(deck)-1)
    card_number = deck[rand_card]
    deck.remove(card_number)
    card = Canvas(window, width=40, height=40, bg='yellow')
    card.place(x=50, y=50, anchor=CENTER)
    card_number_text = card.create_text(20, 20, text=card_number, tags=card_number)
    card.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: get_number(event, card_number_text))  # or you can use: card.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: print(card_number))
    card.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag)


def drag(event):
    # This is better for move a widget
    cx = window.winfo_pointerx() - window.winfo_rootx()
    cy = window.winfo_pointery() - window.winfo_rooty()
    event.widget.place(x=cx, y=cy)

def get_number(event, number):
    print(event.widget.itemcget(number, "text"))


button1 = Button(window, text="Generate Card", command=pick_card)
button1.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

I've modified the `drag(event)` function and wrote two ways for get the current card value, for store it you can use some `global varibles` or create a `class`, the second would be better